# Заполнение всей панели таблицей

Tags: java

Есть класс панели, куда добавлена панель.
Проблема в том, что таблица не занимает всю панель, а надо чтобы занимала.
Как это реализовать?

```
    import java.awt.Cursor;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Image;

    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.JTable;

public class panelRight extends JPanel {
    private Image img;
    mButtons b = new mButtons();

    public panelRight() {

        final JTable tbl = new JTable(100, 5);
        Cursor cursor = new Cursor(1);
        tbl.setCursor(cursor);
        JScrollPane scrlPn = new JScrollPane(tbl);
        add(scrlPn);
    }

}
```

Скрин:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, нужно использовать `BorderLayout`. То есть заменить

```
add(scrlPn);
```

на

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
add(scrlPn, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: спасибо

не подскажешь еще, как самому установить размеры каждого столбца, можно ссылку на ресурс "где почитать")